# How to keep track of the index of elements in a list after I sorted it?

Tags: python, list, optimization

Ps1, Ps2, Ps3, Ps4, Ps5 and F are given values. I need to find the values for a, b, c, d and e that maximize the result of this equation:

60 + a (Ps1-F) + b (Ps2-F) + c (Ps3-F) + d (Ps4-F) + e (Ps5-F) = 0

The constraints are that the sum of a, b, c, d and e can never be less than 20 and each of these elements can only be either 0 or 10.

This is what I did so far:

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0

values = [a, b, c, d, e]


def roll_over(f, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5):
    counter = 0
    constants = [p1 - f, p2 - f, p3 - f, p4 - f, p5 - f]

    for i in constants:
        if i >= 0:
            values[counter] = 10
        else:
            values[counter] = 0
        counter = counter + 1
```

After this, I need to handle the case in which I only have negative values in the list constants (and thus the above code only gives me 0's for the list values. The ideal strategy is to take the two greatest elements in the list constants (even if negative) and assign the number 10 to the two elements in list values with the same index, while keeping the other as 0's.

However, I get stuck there because if I find that, for example, Ps4-F and Ps2-F are the two greatest numbers by sorting the list constantly, I cannot find a way to get back to their corresponding elements in values (which would be d and b respectively).

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you check for them not being less thatn 20? or is this adssumed?

Comment: That's the missing part of code, the one I got stuck with. It'd be:

if sum(values) <= 20:
...

Then I was thinking of sorting the list constants to find the two greatest numbers and assign the number 10 to the corresponding elements in values, but I couldn't find a way.

Comment: I ave edited my answer.. hope it helps

Comment: What exactly needs to be maximized ?  is it the sum of a,b,c,d,e ?  or are you looking to maximize `60 + a*(Ps1-F) + b*(Ps2-F) + c*(Ps3-F) + d*(Ps4-F) + e*(Ps5-F) > 0` ?

Comment: @johnashu thank you!!!

Comment: @AlainT. I need to maximize the result of 60 + a*(Ps1-F) + b*(Ps2-F) + c*(Ps3-F) + d*(Ps4-F) + e*(Ps5-F), considering that (Ps1-F), (Ps2-F), etc. are given values.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have only 5 variables with 2 possible values each, there will only be 32 possible combinations, you can afford to use a brute force approach for this and check every valid combination to get the one with the maximum result:

```
def fn(a,b,c,d,e):
    Ps1,Ps2,Ps3,Ps4,Ps5,F = 1.5, 2.3, 1.0, 0.8, 4.9, 1.9 # your given values
    return 60 + a*(Ps1-F) + b*(Ps2-F) + c*(Ps3-F) + d*(Ps4-F) + e*(Ps5-F)


from itertools import product

candidates = (values for values in product(*[(0,10)]*5) if sum(values)>=20)
a,b,c,d,e  = max( candidates, key=lambda values:fn(*values))
```

output:

```
print(a,b,c,d,e, "=", fn(a,b,c,d,e))
# 0 10 0 0 10 = 94.4
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, you need a function like this.

It copies the list, finds the 2 biggest using heapq.largest, replaces them with 10 or 0 and returns the new list..

```
def replace_with_10(values):
    import heapq

    # get the largest 2 values in the list.
    largest, second_largest = heapq.nlargest(2, values)
    # >>> -4 -5

    # enumerate over the list applying hte changes..
    for idx, num in enumerate(values):
        if num in (largest, second_largest):
            values[idx] = 10
        else:
            values[idx] = 0
    return values

values = replace_with_10([-11, -5, -50, -4, -52])
# >>> [0, 10, 0, 10, 0]
```